# SendGrid Email Validation Over Limit

Tags: validation, email, sendgrid

With SendGrid email validation API, what kind of response do I expect when I make more requests than my limit?

The pricing plan mentions limit of 2500 (Pro) / 5000 (Premium). Is that number counted per month? What do I need to do if I need more than that?